# Accessing new element added by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm making an AJAX request with $.get command. When that completes I append the HTML code to my existing div. After all my code got appended I noticed that I can't access my newly added code with jQuery selector. I've read other DOM refreshing question but those are related to 'click' events. I just wanted to access my added id with $("#xxxxxxxx")

For example, I added

```
<div id="aaa1"></div><div id="aaa2"></div><div id="aaa3"></div>
```

into my existing

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

What I wanted to add is in temp.html file, so I used `$("#container").load("temp.html");` Things got added nicely but I can't access it. ( Using `alert($("#aaa1").html())` returnd `undefined` )

Comment: `alert($("aaa1").html()` should be `alert($("#aaa1").html()` ??

Comment: you need to use `$('#aaa1')` (note the #-sign)

Comment: `.load()` works asynchronously. If you want to access the newly added content, do so from its callback.

Comment: Also be sure you are not duplicating html `id` attributes...

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped :P It's already `alert($("#aaa1").html()` in my code. About `id` attribute i've dynamically rename it by appending number to `id` as I generating code so it won't duplicate. (Checked in Firebug)

Comment: And thanks about `.load()` being async! I've never noticed that it was an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#container").load("temp.html" ,function(){
    alert($("#aaa1").html());     
});
```